# Help Understand Salesforce Governor Limit and Apex

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, governorlimits

I am having a tough time understanding the governor's limits. I have a huge flow that does a bunch of CRUD. I keep getting an email that goes like this:

```
Caused the following Apex resource warnings:

Number of SOQL queries: 62 out of 100
```

Initially, I moved the big Database calls to an Apex using Apex Action within the flow to alleviate the heavy load to the Apex, but I am still getting the same email.

[image]

So does that mean if I call an apex class from within the flow is still tied by the rules of Flow Governance? i.e. only 100 Queries compared to 200 in apex?

Comment: It's 100 per transaction. Your entire flow is likely one transaction. You can/should bulkify your flow to reduce the number of database calls and/or split the flow into multiple transactions. There are a number of Q&As on both of these topics here, do a search.

Comment: ahh okay, that makes sense, thank you! 
Breaking transaction gave me the answer

Comment: @SimpleCode You said "200 in apex" - note that is only for async Apex.  For synchronous Apex, the limit is 100 and of course includes the queries that the Flow is doing.

Comment: @identigral - you should add your comment as an answer